# Какие свойства можно прописать, чтоб галлерея уменьшалась подобным образом?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS

```css
.gallery__inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    gap: 15px;
    
}
```

Comment: Вам необходим функционал для изменения размера галереи или же свойства css для адаптивных картинок?

Comment: свойства css для адаптивных картинок

Comment: max-width: 100%;
height: auto;